# Charindex() functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring, charindex

Can anyone explain the actual working of CharIndex() function in SQL Server. I have gone through MSDN and other websites. But I got few doubts after reading those. I am able to understand with 2 parameters. But I am not able to understand output once we use the third parameter(Start position)Please see the below examples.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 3);
-- Result: 7

SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 8);
-- Result: 12
```

I am not able to understand why the results like that for the above two.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx says *start_location -
Is an integer or bigint expression at which the search starts. If start_location is not specified, is a negative number, or is 0, the search starts at the beginning of expressionToSearch.*

Answer (score 2):

From **[`CHARIDNEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)**

> **start_location**
>
> Is an integer or bigint expression at which the search starts. If start_location is not specified, is a negative number, or is 0, the
>   search starts at the beginning of expressionToSearch.

The searching is from `^` symbol forward.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 3); -- Result: 7
                         ^---x-------->   

SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 8); -- Result: 12
                              ^---x--->
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd parameter is the starting position, so any matching patterns prior to this point are skipped.

So in your examples:-

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 3)
```

Starting position is 3, so the first 't' is skipped and returns the next one starting at position 7.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 8)
```

Starting position is 8, so the first and second instances of 't' are skipped and returns the next one starting at position 12.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument (optional) to `charindex` is the start position for the search.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('t', 'TechOnTheNet.com', 3); -- Result: 7
```

In this case, the search for `t` starts at 3. But the output will be the position of `t` in the original string.

You can see it is similar for your other example as well.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is the start index, so that indicates the first string position where it will look for the specified character.  The output is the absolute offset (one-based) of the next occurrence of the specified character.

In your example there is a T character at offsets 1, 7, and 12 (it's case-insensitive). The function returns the first occurrence greater than or equal to the specified start offset.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have gone through the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) article then i'm really clueless why  you just missed this`CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )`  part of that article.

it clearly said everything you want to know here.

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ]
```

**expressionToFind**

```
Is a character expression that contains the sequence to be found. expressionToFind is limited to 8000 characters.
```

**expressionToSearch**

```
Is a character expression to be searched.
```

**start_location**

```
 Is an integer or bigint expression at which the search starts.
 If start_location is not specified(It's OPTIONAL PARAMETER),
 is a negative number, or is 0,
 the search starts at the beginning of expressionToSearch.
```

Comment: Yeah. I have gone through MSDN. But I was thinking that from the start position, it is counting the number of characters till it finds the search string.

Comment: no, it's the position from where to the search starts.